# Replacing newlines in a record by using Perl or shell script

Tags: perl, shell, expression

I need to remove newlines in a field of a text file. For example:

input file looks like:

```
"user1","John","Doe","123 a street,
San Francisco,
CA, 94089"
"user2","Foo","Bar","123 x rd., San Jose, CA 95129"
...
```

How do I remove the newlines in the first record?

Answer (score 1):

With full error checking:

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

my $qfn_in  = '...'; 
my $qfn_out = $qfn_in . '.new';

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
    binary => 1,
    eol    => "\n",
});

open(my $fh_in, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $qfn_in)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn_in\": $!\n");

open(my $fh_out, ">:encoding(UTF-8)", $qfn_out)
   or die("Can't create \"$qfn_out\": $!\n");

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
   s/\n/ /g for @$row;
   $csv->print($fh, $row) 
      or die("Error writing to \"$qfn_out\": " . $csv->error_diag() . "\n");
}

$csv->eof()  
   or die("Error reading \"$qfn_in\": " . $csv->error_diag() . "\n");

close($fh_in);
close($fh_out) 
   or die("Error writing to \"$qfn_out\": $!\n");

rename($qfn_out, $qfn_in) 
   or die("Can't overwrite \"$qfn_in\" with \"$qfn_out\": $!\n");
```

Comment: $fh_out should be opened for output (>); $fn_* != $fh_+ (close).

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, use `chomp`. You probably want to chomp each line that ends in a comma:

```
perl -pe 'chomp if /,$/' input.txt
```

The input file looks like a CSV file. It might be better to use a module to parse it: [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV)

Answer (score 0):

the following will achieve this, although the `Text::CSV_XS` solution is much more robust:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my $str =<<"DATA";
"user1","John","Doe","123 a street,
San Francisco,
CA, 94089"
"user2","Foo","Bar","123 x rd., San Jose, CA 95129"
DATA

$str =~ s/,\n/,/g;

print $str;
```